# What type of connector can I use for repetitive testing of board with standard headers?

Tags: connector, testing

What type of connector (besides the regular female counterpart) could be used for repetitive connection/disconnection of these pins in circuit boards?

[image: pins in circuit board]

The problem with using the regular female connector is that it wears down and needs to be replaced regularly. Take into consideration that about 150 tests are performed each day so that is around 3000 times each month the cable needs to be connected and disconnected.

Also, this process is performed by a person (not a robot) so it must be something easy to connect/disconnect.

Comment: Typically high rate of testing would use other forms like pogopins and test points instead of populated headers.

Comment: Have you researched connection methods used for test fixtures and on ATE on the Internet?

Comment: You can contact those pins with special spring loaded pogo pins in a test fixture. If you don't have a test fixture, you should probably have one made if you are testing up to 150 units per day. The pogo pins may wear out but can be replaced pretty easily. Like in Ralph's answer.

Comment: @TonyM, yes, I did some research and found out custom fixtures with pogo pins. In this case the circuit boards come with standard headers (I did not know thats what they were called). I was wondering if some other type of connector existed that could last longer than using regular female connector

Comment: Do you have access to a 3d printer? I'd probably design something similar to a clothespin, with a cutout for the 1x4 header and another 1x4 male connector inside that's pushed against the existing contact, sort of like a radial male-to-male pogo pin.

Comment: Assuming this is your actual connector, you can use a female housing with pogo pins inside. For finer pitch connectors, down to 1mm or 40 mils, there are pre-made assemblies (Tag connect is one) that have suitable pogo pins inside.

Comment: @towe, I do have a 3d printer. It is a good idea to design something like that but I think that the plastic is going to wear off and then the male pins will not be perfectly in contact all the time. It depends on the deisgn I guess...

Answer (score 18):

**Pogo pin**

Connectors that have sliding surfaces have a limited lifetime. Pogo pins apply pressure to the contact and tip type and contact force can be selected to deliver enough current and provide good contact even through flux residue. Pogo pins can be inserted into holders, which allows easy replacement. Pogo pin types from Everett Charles Technologies:

[image: Pogo pin types]

The cup types fit to male pins directly, especially if you have at least 2 mm pitch to allow enough room to fit the stanard pin size with a holder.

Some spring loaded contacts such as Samtec SIB -series can withstand substantial amount of mating cycles, but they are tested and specified orders of magnitude less of cycles than pogo pins.

Usual choice to what you are describing is a pogo pin, unless there are space restrictions. It also allows a no-cost counter part on the device to be tested.

**Intermediate board or cable**

If you are testing PCBAs and need to have the connectors tested too, and the connectors cannot be directly interfaced witha pogo pin, you could have an intermediate board connected to tester electronics with pogo pins. The intermediate board would be swapped every day or would connect to a cable that would be swapped every day.

To make connections you might need a fixture that can push pins to the test board from below and even above. Image courtesy to Ingun.de:
[image: PCBA test fixture]

Comment: Thank for your answer. I read about pogo pins and testing beds, and this type of testing is ideal for the manufacturer of the PCBs. In my case the circuit board is already mounted in the final product but a cable needs to be connected to those pins to send serial commands to the board and do some testing.

Comment: Sure, I don't know the application exactly and the pins I presented are on the larger side. Example of a smaller connector would be TC2030-MCP cable. An many chargers take use of a magnet holding a connector in place and contacts are made with tiny spring loaded pogo-pin type of contacts (Apple laptop charger if I'm not mistaken). You'll find those smaller pins in the ECT catalog too.

Answer (score 16):

The cost of an intermediary sacrificial cable is often an alternate, readily-available, cost-effective solution with a pull tab for optimal axial withdrawal forces to extend life.

Considering it not a shrouded keyed header, a minor concern is reverse orientation by human error.

Comment: A similar idea would be an interposer board that goes between the test board and the DUT. When the connector on the interposer board wears out you just replace it. This might make reverse orientation less likely.

Comment: Right now what we do is using an intermediary sacrificial cable which is changed when it wears down. Its interesting what you say abot the pull tab to extend life. Do you have one example of connector with pull tab that can be used in that 4 pin header? (actually only three pins are needed, so a 3 pin connector would work as well).  The header is a serial connection with Rx Tx and Gnd. If connected in reverse orientation then it simply wont work. Its not an issue for concern to me.  

What @mkeith says about an interposer board, I think would cost more to replace than a simple cable.

Comment: I don't have any example for a 4 pin IDC cable as I imagine the pull force ought to be small compared to 50p pull tabs which is plastic film crimped with IDC cable.  Perhaps training with photo DO and DON'T to prevent stretching socket

Answer (score 9):

Maybe a zero-insertion-force (ZIF) receptacle might be more longer lasting. I've seen this type: -

[image]

But, I don't know if it's available with just four receptacles.

Product page: https://multimedia.3m.com/mws/media/493535O/3mtm-in-line-zip-strip-sockets-ts0362.pdf?&fn=ts0362.pdf

> *The problem with using the regular female connector is that it wears
> down and needs to be replaced regularly.*

If the regular (non ZIF) female part was easily removable then it could be swapped every so often. Maybe you can arrange for it to plug into another socket?

Comment: Yes. something like that with 3 or 4 pins would be ideal.  Or al least something that could be connected to the header that used a similar connection method as the internals of a USB connector (which i believe would last longer than a regular female).

Answer (score 9):

One option that works well for 6-10 pins is [Tag-Connect](https://www.tag-connect.com/), which works with a land area on the DUT and a reusable cable/connector that has spring-loaded pins:

[image]
<sup>Image reproduced from tag-connect.com</sup>

This eliminates the need for a physically-populated part on the DUT since the connector is a part of the PCB design itself, while the test fixture is a handheld cable rather than a fully custom-built fixture assembly.

Note that I have no affiliation with this vendor.

Comment: I use Tag-Conect but do remember another member on here saying they wear out. Not sure how. Maybe just the plastic latches eventually break but that there are latchless versions as well when the cable only needs to be held against the board for a few seconds in production.

Comment: I mean these are just a self centering pogo pin jig.

Comment: Some versions of TC have plastic latches that keep it engaged with the board when pushed in. Those are a weak point and definitely do wear down eventually. Although in my experience it takes quite a while.

Comment: One nice advantage of these is that you can put another Tag-Connect connector on the opposite side of the board (same mounting holes but different signal pads).  Two different debug connectors for the footprint of one.  You can't use them at the same time, but it can save on board space if you - for example - need one connector for in-circuit programming and another for debugging.

Answer (score 5):

Standard answer: surface pads on the board, interfaced to spring (‘pogo’) pins loaded in a fixture that positions the board over the pins.

Cheap-and-cheerful answer for a low pin count like JTAG: board has unpopulated through-hole single row site. Cable has male SIP square header on its end. Insert SIP header into holes, pull the cable to one side with some light tension to tilt/wedge the pins against the side of the holes.

When you get tired of cheap-and-cheerful, make a pogo fixture.

Comment: board comes already with the male headers. A Cheap-and-cheerful cable solution needs to be connected to it to do some testing. Right now it is a cable with regular female connector that is replaced so often, but I am wondering if there is a solution that could last longer

Comment: Take an unsoldered SIP header with slightly longer pins and plug it in to the female cable connector. Then your wearing element is the SIP, not the female connector. It should last a long time.

Answer (score 3):

If this connector is only for test/factory use and it's not something the end-user would ever be expected to use, then I would simply leave that connector unpopulated.  You'll save a few cents on the connector, won't have to change your PCB layout, and you can connect a pogo pin cable directly to the empty holes on the circuit board.

Technically speaking, you don't actually have to connect to that connector.  You have to connect to those *signals*.  Many PCBs have test points that allow you to access various signals without using a formal connector like that.  Trace these signals back to their source and see if you can access them somewhere else.  A test jig with pogo pins can connect to multiple test points and easily give you access to dozens of signals all at once.  I can't tell from the photo but if this is a through-hole connector, you can often flip the board over and use the solder mound on the other end of the connector as if it were a test point.

Some applications use a "bed of nails" connector that's shaped a bit like a claw.  It grabs onto a chip on the circuit board, pressing a probe into each of the chip's external pins.  This would let you access the serial signals directly from the chip itself.  These require a DIP, SOIC, or other type of chip with external pins (not a BGA or similar with connections underneath the chip).  For QFP chips, they make [test clips](https://www.adapt-plus.com/shop?category=test-clips) that slide between the pins and grab the leads from the side.

In a pinch, I've even used a small PCB with [castellated pads](https://www.pcbdirectory.com/community/what-are-castellated-holes-on-a-pcb) to interface with a pin header.  Castellated pads are essentially a plated through hole that's been cut in half.  You're supposed to solder to them, but you can also press the connector against the side of the pin header and make a solid enough connection.  You wouldn't want to sit there and hold the connector in place for half an hour or anything like that but for quick spot-checks or tasks that only take a minute or two, it'll get the job done with minimal wear and tear.

I've also used [retractable hook style probes](https://www.mouser.com/ProductDetail/Altech/973501100?qs=qOhVvio4tz73xGtsWQqbyg%3D%3D) to grab onto header pins or even to the legs of a soldered-on IC.  They're spring loaded so they'll eventually wear out, but they should last a lot longer than a sliding connector. You also have to attach them one pin at a time, but that shouldn't be too terrible since you only have three pins.  Use different colors for each signal to minimize the risk of someone connecting them incorrectly.

Comment: The castellated pads are a good idea. If there is a castellated pad that has the same spacing as the header pins, and some sort of spring or attach mechanism is used to guarantee contact without holding it, then its a valid solution.

Comment: @F.A The castellated pads are really only a "hold it by hand" sort of solution.  If you need something that you don't have to hold, then the retractable hook probes are probably the most reliable solution that doesn't involve building a custom test jig of some sort.

Answer (score 1):

As you want to retain the 2.54 mm header pins, and not replace them with surface touch pads, or some other type of connector, you are faced with the inherent problem caused by the design of the DuPont pins/connections themselves: You need a snug tight fit, which means that the female connector will be difficult to apply without exerting pressure. There don't seem to be an ZIF type sockets for 1x4 2.54 mm header pins.

However, you could use a set of four **narrow diameter springs** (to which test leads are soldered to), which would have slightly more give in them than the female DuPont connector, and not exert as much stress upon the soldered PCB joints when being put on or removed from the header pins. Looking at the specification:

[image: Header pins dimensions]

the pins are 0.65 mm wide, so some springs of inner diameter 0.5 mm would do the job.

Now, whether or not they would be more fiddly to carefully fit on, and remove from, the header pins is another matter, and only repetitive usage/testing would determine how they compare in practice to the regular 1x4 DuPont female connector.

Also, getting hold of 0.5 inner diameter springs that are strong enough to withstand repeated application, without becoming stretched might be a difficult.

However, even commonly available 3 mm inner diameter springs might work, at a pinch, if you thread the pins between the coils, being mindful to avoid the adjacent springs touching - some judicious use of heat shrink over the springs, as **sleeving**. should solve this.

---

Another, arguably simpler, alternative could be to use spring loaded, hooked, test clips, of which a variety exist:

[image: Spring loaded hooked test clips#1] [image: Spring loaded hooked test clips#2]

Use the smaller type, mini test hook, to ensure that all four clips can fit on to the 1x4 header.

In order to reduce the possibility of human error in connecting the clips to the four pins, use multiple colours to colour code each pin:

[image: Multicolour probes]

As your connector is only 1x4, it should not take *that much* longer to attach four clips than one female header connector - maybe a few seconds more, which admittedly would be at least double the time, but not much in the larger scheme of things, when considering the reduced stress placed upon the header pins and their associated solder joints.

Comment: The test clips would need too much time to attach and dettach. Human error may cause  wrong connections.

Comment: Human error could also cause the female 1x4 header connector to be connected in reverse. Also, how long does it take to attach four clips?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution imo is to simply add a short extension to the test lead.

When the female connector wears out you simply remove the extension and replace it.

I recommend buying a [4 pole m12 patch cable](https://www.automationdirect.com/adc/shopping/catalog/cables/sensors_-z-_switches/micro_(m12)_normal_duty_q-z-d_cables/4-pole_micro_(m12)_cables/cdp12-0b-030-aa), cutting it in half and connecting the connector ends together. This creates a short cable which can be disconnected in the middle.

Solder your 4 pin female header connector to one end. And when that wears out the m12 allows the operator to disconnect the end of the cable and replace it.

**Edit:** Updated because I misread the question.

Comment: The pcbs are connected to do some testing. Each time you need to connect a different PCB from the header to the test station so your solution does not apply

Comment: It does still apply. I misread your question and thought you were trying to protect the header, and not the cable, but the same principal applies. Extent the cable with an extension. When the female connector wears out, disconnect the extension and replace it. Bam, new connector. And every replacement only causes one cycle of wear on the actual cable.

Comment: thats what I am doing currently. I was wondering if there was something that could last longer than the female connector (so it needed to be replaced less often)